# JUnit 5 Not able to mock functions called from function under test

Tags: java, junit5, spring-test

I am new to Junit 5 . There are two functions in the class under test , The first function calls the second function and second function returns a value which is used in the first function for processing .
So I have created a mock for this class but not able to mock the second function call When I am testing the first function .

First function --exportOpportunityListing()
Second function -- entityToCsvReport()

```
public class OpportunityReportServiceImpl extends BaseService implements OpportunityReportService {

    @Value("${nfs.mountPath}")
    private String fileMountPath;

    @Value("${take1.url.host}")
    private String take1HostURL;

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Autowired
    MailUtil mailUtil;

    @Autowired
    OpportunityJDBCRepository ojdbc;

    @Override
    @Async
    public void exportOpportunityListing(Map<String, Object> paramMap, List<OpportunityCriteria> lfvo,
            String xRemoteUser) {
        try {
            List<OpportunityJDBCDTO> lo = ojdbc.getOppListWithoutPagination(paramMap, lfvo);
            List<OpportunityReport> exportData = lo.parallelStream().map(this::entityToCsvReport)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            CsvCustomMappingStrategy<OpportunityReport> mappingStrategy = new CsvCustomMappingStrategy<>();
            mappingStrategy.setType(OpportunityReport.class);
            String dirPath = fileMountPath + REPORT_PATH;
            File fileDir = new File(dirPath);
            if (!fileDir.exists()) {
                FileUtils.forceMkdir(fileDir);
            }
            String pathWithoutExtension = dirPath + "opportunity_data_"
                    + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(YYYYMMDDHHMMSS));
            File reportFile = new File(pathWithoutExtension + EXTENSION_CSV);
            Writer writer = new PrintWriter(reportFile);
            StatefulBeanToCsv<OpportunityReport> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<OpportunityReport>(writer)
                    .withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy).build();
            beanToCsv.write(exportData);
            writer.close();
            String zipFilePath = pathWithoutExtension + EXTENSION_ZIP;
            ZipUtil.zip(reportFile, zipFilePath);
            Users remoteUser = usersRepository.findByUsername(xRemoteUser)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new Take1Exception(ErrorMessage.USER_NOT_FOUND_WITH_USERNAME, xRemoteUser));
            Mail mail = Mail.builder().to(new String[] { remoteUser.getEmail() })
                    .model(MailModel.builder().name(remoteUser.getName())
                            .body("Please find attached the opportunity report you requested.").build())
                    .subject("Opportunity Report").attachments(Arrays.asList(new File(zipFilePath))).build();
            mailUtil.sendMail(mail);
            Files.delete(reportFile.toPath());
        } catch (IOException | CsvDataTypeMismatchException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException e) {
            throw new Take1Exception(ErrorMessage.INTERNAL_SERVER_EXCEPTION, e);
        }

    }

    public OpportunityReport entityToCsvReport(OpportunityJDBCDTO o) {
        OpportunityReport or = modelMapper.map(o, OpportunityReport.class);
        or.setCurrency("USD");
        or.setOnline(Boolean.TRUE.equals(o.getIsOnline()) ? "YES" : "NO");
        return or;
    }

}
```

Here is my JUnit Test case .

```
class OpportunityReportServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    OpportunityReportServiceImpl opportunityReportServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    OpportunityReportServiceImpl ors;

    @Mock
    OpportunityJDBCRepository ojdbc;

    @Mock
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Mock
    MailUtil mailUtil;

    @Mock
    ModelMapper mp;

    String username = "anandabhishe";
    String nfusername = "ananda";
    Mail mail;
    List<OpportunityJDBCDTO> lo = new ArrayList<OpportunityJDBCDTO>();
    List<OpportunityReport> lor = new ArrayList<OpportunityReport>();

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(opportunityReportServiceImpl, "fileMountPath", ".");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(opportunityReportServiceImpl, "take1HostURL", "");
        lo.add(new OpportunityJDBCDTO());
        lor.add(new OpportunityReport());

    }

    @Test
    void testExportOpportunityListing() throws IOException {
        OpportunityReport or = new OpportunityReport();
        or.setCurrency("USD");
        or.setOnline("Yes");

        when(ojdbc.getOppListWithoutPagination(getParamMap(), getOppCriteria())).thenReturn(lo);
        when(usersRepository.findByUsername(username)).thenReturn(Optional.of(getUser()));
        doNothing().when(mailUtil).sendMail(mail);
        // doNothing().when(opportunityReportServiceImpl).entityToCsvReport(oj);
        when(opportunityReportServiceImpl.entityToCsvReport(getOpportunityJDBCDTO())).thenReturn(or);
        opportunityReportServiceImpl.exportOpportunityListing(getParamMap(), getOppCriteria(), username);
        assertTrue(true);
        FileUtils.forceDelete(new File("." + REPORT_PATH));
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getParamMap() {
        return new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    private List<OpportunityCriteria> getOppCriteria() {
        List<OpportunityCriteria> loc = new ArrayList<>();
        loc.add(new OpportunityCriteria());
        return loc;
    }

    private OpportunityJDBCDTO getOpportunityJDBCDTO() {
        OpportunityJDBCDTO oj = new OpportunityJDBCDTO();
        oj.setIsOnline(true);
        oj.setApplicationCount(2);
        oj.setCost(200);
        oj.setCountryCode("in");
        oj.setCreationDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        oj.setEndDate(LocalDate.now());
        oj.setLocation("test");
        oj.setOpportunityId(123);
        oj.setOpportunityStatus("test");
        oj.setOpportunityStatusId(1);
        oj.setOpportunityTitle("test");
        oj.setOpportunityType("test");
        oj.setOpportunityTypeColor("test");
        oj.setOpportunityTypeId(1);
        oj.setPublishedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        oj.setPublishedBy("test");
        oj.setPublishedByUserName("test");
        oj.setRegistrationUrl("test");
        oj.setStartDate(LocalDate.now());
        oj.setSummary("test");
        oj.setUserEmail("test");
        oj.setUserFullName("test");
        oj.setUserId(1);
        oj.setUserName("test");
        oj.setVendorName("test");
        return oj;
    }

    private Users getUser() {
        Users user = new Users();
        return user;
    }

}
```

I am getting Null Pointer Exception when the line in Test class is called :

```
when(opportunityReportServiceImpl.entityToCsvReport(getOpportunityJDBCDTO())).thenReturn(or);
```

Comment: I would recommend both that you use constructor injection (because it makes supplying mocks and test data easier) and that you deconstruct your method so that it's doing less: For example, open a file to return a `Writer` in one method, then pass the `Writer` to another method to perform the output. This lets you supply a `StringWriter`, for instance, which can make testing cleaner.

Comment: The class cant be changed as of now , it has been written long back and there are other classes which follow method deconstruction . Sadly , we started writing test cases after the development completed :(

Comment: are there any annotations on the test class? With Mockito you should at least have `@Extension(MocktioExtension.class)`. Furthermore, I don't understand why you mock a public method of your class under test? When you unit-test your classes you usually mock calls to external classes but not methods of the class itself.

Comment: @rieckpil I was getting a NPE when I wasn't mocking the  second method , so I thought of mocking it .

Comment: @AbhishekAnand Since you're using Spring, the class _can_ be changed so far as to use constructor injection, and while the `exportOpportunityListing` API may be unchangeable for now, you can replace that method with a sequence of calls to decomposed methods.

Comment: I assume the NPE might come from not mocking `modelMapper` inside `entityToCsvReport`

Comment: @rieckpil You are correct , I have stubbed modelmapper and now its working fine , I dont need to mock the second function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing mocking the modelmapper stub which is being used in second function , after I added that , the test passed .

```
OpportunityReport or = new OpportunityReport();
        OpportunityJDBCDTO oj = new OpportunityJDBCDTO();
        when(ojdbc.getOppListWithoutPagination(any(HashMap.class), anyList())).thenReturn(lo);
        when(usersRepository.findByUsername(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(getUser()));
        doNothing().when(mailUtil).sendMail(mail);
        doReturn(or).when(mp).map(oj, OpportunityReport.class);
        opportunityReportServiceImpl.exportOpportunityListing(getParamMap(), getOppCriteria(), username);
        assertTrue(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because `opportunityReportServiceImpl` is not a mock - it's the object that you're trying to test, but you're trying to stub a method of it as if it were a mock.

I would recommend that you *don't* try to stub the methods of the object that you're trying to test.  But if you have to, you'll need to declare it as a `@Spy`.  Then to stub it, you'll need the `doReturn/when` syntax instead of `when/thenReturn`.  This might look like

```
doReturn(lo).when(ojdbc).getOppListWithoutPagination(getParamMap(), getOppCriteria());
```